# Is there anyway to grab Google Analytics via some kind of API?

Tags: google-analytics

Basically I have an admin CP I've coded for all my sites and I'd love to integrate the information gathered by Google Analytics on it to avoid having to look at both sites every morning.

BTW I'm using PHP, but I would assume if something like this exists it would just be exported as XML.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

[Here's how to use Yahoo Pipes to scrape your Analytics page](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2008-01-17-n73.html)
[Alternatively, you can export reports and use them](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55561)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend scraping your Analytics page. It's explicitly forbidden in the Google Analytics terms of service.

Comment: Good point.  And they will find out, I have no doubt about that.

Answer (score 1):

There's an official API in private beta.  I'm looking forward to it!

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2008/10/more-enterprise-class-features-added-to.html

Comment: Ahh yes I read about this briefly a week or so ago, don't remember reading it was private :/

Answer (score 0):

Nicolas Lierman has developed an [AIR application that uses an API of his own creation](http://www.aboutnico.be/?p=23) to gather Google analytics data. He refuses to puplish the API though as apparently it exposes some severe security flaws in Analytics interface. Google themselves have never published an API for it.

If you really want to proceed with your plan, you'll have to reverse engineer the interface yourself.